# Python C++ API: How to retrieve lineno attribute of NameError

Tags: python, c++, c, api

I am using the python API for C/C++ and I would like to retrieve the 
line number in case of a NameError.

I followed the instructions found within the question bellow:

[How to retrieve filename and lineno attribute of SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733425/how-to-retrieve-filename-and-lineno-attribute-of-syntaxerror)

and I wrote the following code:

```or-tag-here
PyObject *ptype = NULL, *pvalue = NULL, *ptraceback = NULL;
PyObject *comp = NULL, *eval = NULL;
char code[] = {"A=undef_var"};

comp = Py_CompileString(code, "", Py_file_input);
if (comp) {
    eval = PyEval_EvalCode(comp, PyEval_GetBuiltins(), NULL);
}
if (!comp || !eval) {
     PyErr_PrintEx(1); // inside this function the PyErr_Fetch(ptype, pvalue, ptraceback) is called

     // retrieve the information gained from PyErr_Fetch() called inside PyErr_PrintEx(1) 
     pvalue     = PySys_GetObject("last_value"); 
     ptype      = PySys_GetObject("last_type");  
     ptraceback = PySys_GetObject("last_traceback");  
     PyErr_NormalizeException(ptype, pvalue, ptraceback);

    PyObject* line_no = PyObject_GetAttrString(pvalue,"lineno");
    if (line_no) {
         PyObject* line_no_str = PyObject_Str(line_no);
         PyObject* line_no_unicode =     PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(line_no_str,"utf-8", "Error");
         char *actual_line_no = PyBytes_AsString(line_no_unicode);
    }
}
```

The code above returns the correct line number, in case the python code 
contains a SyntaxError (e.g. for a simple python code like "A="), 
but in case of a NameError the line number is not set correctly to the pvalue object (e.g. for the python code: "A=undefined_var").

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you just use boost library for this?
Then you could check out this stackoverflow link:
[How to get Python exception text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418015/how-to-get-python-exception-text/37780954)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the boost library. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do note that you **absolutely have to check** the return value of **each and every `Py_*` function**, separately, and act accordingly.

Comment: You'd notice that `NameError` doesn't even have the attribute `lineno`.

Comment: What's the _Python_ version (and _OS_) that you're using? For me, _Python35_ on _Win_ throws an _Access violation_ (_segfault_) in `Py_CompileString`.

Comment: @Antti Haapala I do check them separately, I have changed the code litle bit. I am interested in cases that the parsing is Ok and the evaluation fails..

Comment: I don't see the check for the return value of `PyObject_GetAttrString(pvalue,"lineno");` not being `NULL`

Comment: @CristiFati Python 3.3 on windows 7

Comment: *"NameError the line number is not set correctly to the pvalue object (e.g. for the python code: "A=undefined_var")."* - so what happens *here*?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I cannot retrieve the line number of the error...because of the evaluation error. The undefined_var is unknown and this makes the PyEval_EvalCode to fail.

Comment: *it does fail because an exception was raised*. Your code is again incorrect. You have the exception **only when the `eval` failed**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My initial code was transferred  here by hand, and it is not my original code. I just wanted to give a general idea of my problem. Don't be so strict.  I have added some extra checks to catch the exceptions for both parsing and evaluation errors. But my question still has to do on how to retrieve the line number when an evaluation error happens. Disregard the two functions I use, lets say I use the PyRun_String function which parses and executes the code. I had the same problem as well...

Comment: If you had done it correctly, you would have *known* that `NameError` doesn't have the attribute `lineno` and *that* is why it doesn't work. You need to access the [traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796510/accessing-a-python-traceback-from-the-c-api)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for your last answer. I have read this post before you mentioned it, but I have tried it upon SyntaxError and the traceback was either NULL or TypeNone and I thought that it would not work with me. Now I tried it upon NameError and worked.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of  @Antti Haapala and considering the solutions posted to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796510/accessing-a-python-traceback-from-the-c-api) I concluded to the solution below:

```
PyObject *ptype = NULL, *pvalue = NULL, *ptraceback = NULL;
PyObject *compile_obj = NULL, *eval_obj = NULL;
PyObject *line_no = NULL, *line_no_str = NULL, *line_no_unicode = NULL;
char *actual_line_no = NULL;
char code[] = { "A=undef_var" };
int line_num = 0;

compile_obj = Py_CompileString(code, "", Py_file_input);
if (compile_obj) {
    eval_obj = PyImport_ExecCodeModule((char *)"", compile_obj);
}
if (!compile_obj || !eval_obj) {
    PyErr_PrintEx(1); // inside this function the PyErr_Fetch(ptype, pvalue, ptraceback) is called
                      // retrieve the information gained from PyErr_Fetch() called inside PyErr_PrintEx(1) 
    pvalue     = PySys_GetObject("last_value");
    ptype      = PySys_GetObject("last_type");
    ptraceback = PySys_GetObject("last_traceback");
    if (ptype) {
        PyErr_NormalizeException(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
    }
    if (compile_obj) { // NameError
        if (ptraceback) {
            PyTracebackObject *tb_o = (PyTracebackObject *)ptraceback;
            line_num = tb_o->tb_lineno;
        }
    } else { //Syntax Error
        line_no = PyObject_GetAttrString(pvalue, "lineno");
        if (line_no) {
            line_no_str = PyObject_Str(line_no);
            if (line_no_str)     line_no_unicode = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(line_no_str, "utf-8", "Error");
            if (line_no_unicode) actual_line_no = PyBytes_AsString(line_no_unicode);
            if (actual_line_no)  line_num = atoi(actual_line_no);

            Py_XDECREF(line_no);
            Py_XDECREF(line_no_str);
            Py_XDECREF(line_no_unicode);
        }
    }
}
Py_XDECREF(compile_obj);
Py_XDECREF(eval_obj);

return line_num;
```

Comment: You're missing *at least 8* return value checks in ths code - additionally you've got several leaks here.

Comment: Additionally, you're just *assuming* the return value.